# How to type redux thunk with middleware in typescript

Tags: typescript, redux

So I have a SPFx webpart (uses typescript) into with I added Redux. Now everything works, but the *thunk* functions need to be typed and I can't figure out how to type them.

So here is the action I am trying to dispatch:

```
  export const setListByMiddelware:any = (listId:string) => (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch(listIdAdded(listId));
    dispatch(spApiCallBegan({
        method: GET_LIST_ITEMS,
        options: {
            listId
        },
        onSuccess: itemsAdded.type
    }));
  }
```

And here is the SharePoint middleware that does the SP call:

```
import SP from '../../services/SharePointService';
import * as actions from '../SP_API';

const api = store => next => async action => {
    if(action.type !== actions.spApiCallBegan.type) {
        next(action);
        return;
    }

    const { method, options, onSuccess, onError, onStart } = action.payload;

    if(onStart)  {
        store.dispatch({ type: onStart });
    }

    next(action);

    try {
        const result = await SP[method](options);

        store.dispatch(actions.spApiCallSuccess(result));
        if(onSuccess) {
            store.dispatch({
                type: onSuccess,
                payload: result
            });
        }
    } catch(ex) {
        store.dispatch(actions.spApiCallFailed(ex.message));
        if(onError) {
            store.dispatch({ 
                type: onError,  
                payload: ex.message 
            });
        }
    }
}

export default api;
```

Now as you can see I solved this by simply typing the *thunk* to `any` and that works just fine, but I would like to strongly type it, because these are the functions that my components actually use.

This is the stack I am using:
redux@4.0.5
react-redux@7.2.3
@reduxjs/toolkit@1.5.1

I'm having real trouble typing the Redux as you can see I more or less gave up on that and google is not much of a help on this. As a result my Redux code is mostly untyped.

As for typscript I think I am using TS 3.3 with comes with SPFx 1.11.0, with is the SPFx version I am using.

**Edit**
So as pointed out by *markerikson* then I have read the official Redux doc on typing Redux here:
https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript#type-checking-middleware

However when I implemented it I get: **Type '(listId: string) => (dispatch: any, getState: any) => void' is not assignable to type 'ThunkAction<void, IListSate, unknown, AnyAction>'.
Types of parameters 'listId' and 'dispatch' are incompatible.
Type 'ThunkDispatch<IListSate, unknown, AnyAction>' is not assignable to type 'string'.** for *thunk* and **'api' is referenced directly or indirectly in its own type annotation.** for the middleware.

This is the store setup I am using:

```
import { configureStore, getDefaultMiddleware } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import listRedurcer, { IListSate} from './lists';
import SP_API from './middleware/SP_API';


const store = configureStore({
    reducer: listRedurcer,
    middleware: [
        ...getDefaultMiddleware(),
        SP_API
    ],
    devTools : {
        name: 'ReduxList'
    }
});

// Infer the `RootState` and `AppDispatch` types from the store itself
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
// Inferred type: {posts: PostsState, comments: CommentsState, users: UsersState}
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;

export default store;
```

For the thunk I also used this `ThunkAction<void, RootState, string, AnyAction>` but I got the same error.

Answer (score 4):

The [Redux docs "Usage with TypeScript" page specifically covers typing middleware and thunks](https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript#type-checking-middleware):

A custom middleware would look like:

```
import { Middleware } from 'redux'

import { RootState } from '../store'

export const exampleMiddleware: Middleware<
  {}, // Most middleware do not modify the dispatch return value
  RootState
> = storeApi => next => action => {
  const state = storeApi.getState() // correctly typed as RootState
}
```

and for thunks:

```
import { AnyAction } from 'redux'
import { sendMessage } from './store/chat/actions'
import { RootState } from './store'
import { ThunkAction } from 'redux-thunk'

export const thunkSendMessage = (
  message: string
): ThunkAction<void, RootState, unknown, AnyAction> => async dispatch => {
  const asyncResp = await exampleAPI()
  dispatch(
    sendMessage({
      message,
      user: asyncResp,
      timestamp: new Date().getTime()
    })
  )
}

function exampleAPI() {
  return Promise.resolve('Async Chat Bot')
}
```

**update**

It sounds like you're trying to use `ThunkAction` like this:

```
export const setListByMiddelware : ThunkAction = (listId:string) => (dispatch, getState) => {}
```

That's incorrect. `setListByMiddelware` is not a `ThunkAction` - it *returns* a `ThunkAction`. A correct usage would be:

```
export const setListByMiddelware = (listId:string) : ThunkAction => (dispatch, getState) => {}
```

Also, your `middleware` parameter to the store is wrong:

- The `middleware` parameter should be a callback that accepts `getDefaultMiddleware` as its argument
- You should then call it, and use the array's `prepend` and `concat` methods to get the correct types set up:

```js
const store = configureStore({
    reducer: listRedurcer,
    middleware: getDefaultMiddleware => getDefaultMiddleware().concat(SP_API),
    devTools : {
        name: 'ReduxList'
    }
});
```

See https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#correct-typings-for-the-dispatch-type

Comment: So I did read the doc, maybe I should have clarified that. Anyway when I use the type `ThunkAction<void, RootState, unknown, AnyAction>` then I get the following error **Type '(listId: string) => (dispatch: any, getState: any) => void' is not assignable to type 'ThunkAction<void, IListSate, unknown, AnyAction>'.
  Types of parameters 'listId' and 'dispatch' are incompatible.
    Type 'ThunkDispatch<IListSate, unknown, AnyAction>' is not assignable to type 'string'.** I'm sorry I just do not get it I even used `ThunkAction<void, RootState, string, AnyAction>`

Comment: Show where you're using the `ThunkAction` type?

Comment: Yes I tried to use it, but I guess I am using is wrong, when I applied it to the `setListByMiddelware` *thunk* then I simply got the error above.

Comment: Can you update your question to show where and how you are using the `ThunkAction` type?

Comment: It seems like the problem is that they cannot use `RootState` to type the middleware while also deriving the `RootState` type from `store` as this is circular (since the `store` depends on the middleware).  I would recommend explicitly typing `RootState`.  Do you have a better idea?

Comment: No, `RootState` doesn't depend on the middleware at all - just the reducer. I don't see any further updates to the question, so I don't know what the actual problem is here. A correct usage would be: `const myThunk = (id: string) : ThunkAction<w,x,y,z> => (dispatch, getState) => {}`. In other words, "the actual function being returned is a `ThunkAction`", as shown in the example I pasted. Based on the error, it sounds like it's actually being used as `const myThunk : ThunkAction =`, which is wrong.

Comment: @markerikson I am able to reproduce the circular referencing issue.  See [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-toolkit-circular-type-error-ymliz?file=/src/store/index.ts) and [TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/w8v6Mm)

Comment: Yeah, in that case, the workaround is to write a separate `rootReducer` function, and do `type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>`, instead of from `store.getState`.

Comment: So I was using the `ThunkAction` wrong but now I get this: *Argument of type 'ThunkAction<void, IListSate, unknown, AnyAction>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'.
  Property 'type' is missing in type 'ThunkAction<void, IListSate, unknown, AnyAction>' but required in type 'AnyAction'.*

Comment: That most likely means that you're trying to dispatch a thunk, but you're using the plain version of `dispatch` that doesn't understand what thunks are. Please follow the instructions in [the Redux "Usage with TS" docs page for creating typed hooks and using them](https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript#define-typed-hooks).

Answer (score 1):

`ThunkAction<void, RootState, string, AnyAction>` would be appropriate if you created your thunk in one go, like `setListByMiddelware=(dispatch, getState, listId:string)=>{}`, but `setListByMiddelware` is not a thunk itself, it is more of a thunk factory, so you need  its type to reflect it, try

```
const setListByMiddelware:(listId:string)=>ThunkAction<void, RootState, never, AnyAction> = 
  (listId:string) => (dispatch, getState) => {
```

Comment: When I tried your solution I got **Argument of type 'ThunkAction<void, IListSate, never, AnyAction>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'.
  Property 'type' is missing in type 'ThunkAction<void, IListSate, never, AnyAction>' but required in type 'AnyAction'.**

Comment: Looks like it doesn't pick up `dispatch` type correctly, try `dispatch:Dispatch`

Comment: Same issue, this is the implementation I tried: `export const setListByMiddelware:(listId:string)=>ThunkAction<void, RootState, never, AnyAction> = (listId:string) => (dispatch:Dispatch, getState) => { /* thunk code */}`

Comment: And the error is exactly the same?.. try `dispatch:ThunkDispatch<RootState,never, AnyAction>` maybe?

Comment: yes that worked, but I'm sorry I do not know who's answer to accept, because I got my answers from all the submitted answers

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you! (that's the main thing anyways :) )

Answer (score 1):

> 'api' is referenced directly or indirectly in its own type annotation.

You get this error because the middleware type depends on the `RootState` type which is derived from `store`.  But the `store` type depends on the middleware so you have a circular typing.

One way around this is to define the type for `RootState` without using `store`.  In your case your entire reducer is `listReducer`, so you can do:

```
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof listReducer>;
```

That will work with the `api` type suggested by @markerikson

```
const api: Middleware<{}, RootState> = store => next => async action => {
```

---

`setListByMiddleware` is a function whose *return type* is a `ThunkAction`.  The function itself is not a `ThunkAction`.

```
export const setListByMiddelware = (
  listId: string
): ThunkAction<void, RootState, never, AnyAction> => (dispatch, getState) => {
  dispatch(listIdAdded(listId));
  dispatch(
    spApiCallBegan({
      method: GET_LIST_ITEMS,
      options: {
        listId
      },
      onSuccess: itemsAdded.type
    })
  );
};
```